# Concurrent bulk saving - duplicate item in mysql with JPA

Tags: mysql, jpa, concurrency, transactions

I am using JPA's saveAll method for bulk save of a list of employees into mysql database in a microservice architecture.

However, there could be duplicates and concurrent requests( anywhere between 2 to 7 requests at the same time).
How can I handle duplicates in such a scenario ?

Two possible solutions i can think of:-

1. fetch records and eliminate duplicate employees from the list before calling saveAll.
   Problem: concurrent requests could result in race condition and exceptions
2. catch the exception and retry the operation
   Problem: recursive approach is not considered a best practice as it could lead to large number of iterations ?

What can i do in such a situation ?

Comment: Be carefull. The database will see a problem only after a flush of your entities. All your bulk insert will be lost if a single problem arises. And then, you'll have to find the origin of the problem.

Comment: where would your employee list be coming from that it contains duplicates? Each 'batch' needs to validate its data and save it. How you go about getting the data and feeding it into processes/batches should dictate how you handle retries, and remember that failures can happen for other issues, like network blips, and need to be retried as well. If you have validation in the batch process, it is just a matter of reexecuting that process on that batch of data any number of times util it is successful - Maybe see JMS, Kafka or java thread pools instead of recursion and loops.

Comment: In my event-driven microservice architecture, it is possible that duplicate events being received with a time gap of milliseconds trigger the same get api twice, and the response contains the batch / lsit of objects to be saved to db.